# How can I see is the visitor Client or Guest in same route in API

Tags: laravel

I have project laravel10. I have some of API. I use Laravel Sanctum for Auth . Now in header API I have some information appear when user Auth.

```json
"data": {
    "UserData": [],
    "navbarData": [
      {
        "title": "Home",
        "path": "/"
      },
      {
        "title": "AboutUs",
        "path": "/AboutUs"
      },
      {
        "title": "ContactUs",
        "path": "/ContactUs"
      },

      ]

  }
```

My header API function

```
public function index(Request $request):JsonResponse
{
 

    if (auth()->check()) {
        $user = auth()->check();
       // dd($user);
        $this->body['UserData'] = UserResource::collection($user);
    } elseif(!auth()->check()) {
        $this->body['UserData'] = [];
      
    }



    $Categories = Menu::query()->where('active', 1)->orderBy('rank', 'ASC')->get();
    
    $this->body['navbarData'] = MenuResource::collection($Categories);

   
   return response()->json(['data'=>$this->body,  'error'=>''], 200);

}
```

My login API:

```
 public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
{

    $validate = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',

    ]);



    if (Auth::attempt($validate)) {
        $user = auth()->user();

        $user->update(['fcm_token' => $request->fcm_token]);

        $this->message = __('front.login_successfully');
        $this->body['user'] = UserResource::make($user);
         $token = $user->createToken($user->name);

         return response()->json(['message'=>$this->message ,'token'=>$token->plainTextToken,'user'=>$this->body, 'error'=>''], 200);
    } else {

        $this->message = __('front.auth_failed');
        return response()->json(['message'=>$this->message , 'error'=>''], 200);
    }


}
```

In header API I want to see if the visitor guest or client like this photo:

[image]

I know must use token, but how display Array in header API in case I have token or not?

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['api','Cors']], function(){


Route::get('/header', [SettingController::class, 'index']);
```

});

How can I do it in same route?
I use API to react js front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code to the given code that will work with and without authorization:

```
if (auth()->check()) {
    $user = auth()->check();
   // dd($user);
    $this->body['UserData'] = UserResource::collection($user);
} elseif(!auth()->check()) {
    $this->body['UserData'] = [];
  
}
```

To

```
if (auth()->guard('sanctum')->check()) {
    $user = auth()->guard('sanctum')->user();
    // dd($user);
    $this->body['UserData'] = $user;
} else {
    $this->body['UserData'] = [];
}
```